# Using Permission Set in Validation Rule

Tags: community, validation-rule

Currently I have this in a Validation Rule:

```
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"
```

I would like to add another condition that checks a Permission Set. I have found a solution that uses Custom Permissions and I followed the following steps:

1) Create the Custom Permission Set that needs to be referenced
2) Create a Custom Permission called the same name as the Custom Permission Set
3) Add the Custom Permission to the Custom Permission Set
4) Reference the Custom Permission as a Global Variable in the required Formula/Workflow Rules/Validation Rule ($Permission.Custom_Permission_Name).

So what does that look like in the Validation Rule? If I want to only allow System Administrators and members of my Permission Set to do change certain fields. . .

```
AND($Setup.Master_Automation__c.ValidationRulesEnabled__c == true, 
Locked__c == false, 
NOT( ISNEW() ), 
OR(ISCHANGED(ADCVD_Order__c), ISCHANGED(Investigation__c),ISCHANGED(Petition__c),ISCHANGED(Segment__c),ISCHANGED(Suspension_Agreement__c)),
AND( $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
NOT($Permission.ADCVD_App_Modify_Parents))
)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: I think this question is more useful with actual field names instead of genericized ones, so I've rejected your edit to sfdcfox's answer and rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, your new rule is just fine, but it could be optimized a bit to make it easier to read.

---

Strictly speaking, the `$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"` is no longer necessary; you can add Custom Permissions to a Profile as well as a Permission Set.

You can reduce your code to just:

```
AND(
  $Setup.Master_Automation__c.ValidationRulesEnabled__c, 
  NOT(OR(Locked__c,ISNEW()), 
  OR(ISCHANGED(ADCVD_Order__c), 
    ISCHANGED(Investigation__c),
    ISCHANGED(Petition__c),
    ISCHANGED(Segment__c),
    ISCHANGED(Suspension_Agreement__c)
  ),
  NOT($Permission.ADCVD_App_Modify_Parents)
)
```

Note that I applied [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to convert the Locked__c and ISNEW from a NOT A AND NOT B to a NOT (A OR B); feel free to leave it the way it was if you don't understand how this works (or just trust that it does).